# How to convert sql query to eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how to convert sql to eoquent

```
$getAllRequirementRecord = Requirement::select()
  ->join('requirement_locations','requirements.id','=','requirement_locations.requirement_id')
  ->join('locations','requirement_locations.location_id','=','locations.id')
  ->where('isdelete',2)
  ->where('requirements.id',$id)->get();
```

help to solve this problems

Comment: Can you please provide your SQL Query or explain a little bit more about what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: i have requirement model.  that can be relation between requirement_recruiter and requirement_location. requirement_location are relation to the location model. I can try to get location data from requirement model

Comment: First, your `->select()` is useless here. You can do `Requirement::join` and before `->get()` you will be able to use `->select('id', 'name', '.......')`.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not so clear. Are you looking for a general tool which can convert any SQL query to Eloquent or you are just stuck to convert your SQL into eloquent? I am not sure that we can convert SQL to eloquent as general database table name does not tell which eloquent model to use. But you can convert your SQL query to Laravel query builder using this [online tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20180401104858/http://www.midnightcowboycoder.com/)

Comment: You didn't say if you have appropriate models for those tables.

Comment: hi @HarshilVasani, could you help us by adding the original sql query and table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we've an eloquent Model named Requirement and we've a database table named requirements associated with that model and we have another model named requirementLocation associated with a database table named requirement_locations.

and we have a database relation ship between both tables "requirements" & "requirement_locations" based on the requirement_id

Requirement Model:

```
class Requirement extends Model{
  protected $table = 'requirements';
}
```

RequirementLocation Model:

```
class RequirementLocation extends Model{
  protected $table = 'requirement_locations';
}
```

and Now we need to setup a relationship between these two models like the database tables .. so inside the Requirement we're gonna use has many relationship

```
use App\RequirementLocation;

class Requirement extends Model{
  protected $table = 'requirements';

  public function locations(){
     return $this->hasMany(RequirementLocation::class);
  }
}
```

and simply to fetch your data use

```
$id = 1;
$getAllRequirementRecord = Requirement->whereHas('locations' , function($query){
   $query->where('isdelete',2);

})->where('id',$id)->with('locations')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created Requirement, Location and RequirementLocation models

So first add this code in Requirement.php model file:

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('RequirementLocation', 'requirement_locations');
}

Then access the requirements like this :

$requirement = Requirement::where('id', $requirement_id)->first();

Now you can access locations like this :

$requirement->locations;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eloquent with SQL raw query likewise:

```
$activeusers = User::selectRaw('users.name, count(*) submitted_games')
    ->join('games', 'games.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->groupBy('users.name')
    ->orderBy('submitted_games', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

To output to the screen the last queries ran you can use this :

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```